# How to make a right DTO class for request XML body on consuming Web API service

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, poco, restsharp

I am using RestSharp with C# codes to PUT data object (my_object) for a WEB API service operation that supports only XML format.

**My question:**
How can I make a right DTO class (e.g. Analytics, please see below) such that on calling request.AddBody(my_object) method of RestSharp, RestSharp is able to convert a data piece Timestamp to XML attribute along with other properties of Analytics DTO class?

my_object in method call request.AddBody(my_object)  is custom AnalyticsLogs DTO class (please see below).

The following is an example **request Xml body** the Web API service operation requires:

```
<AnalyticsLogs>
  <Analytics Timestamp="1999-05-31T11:20:00">
    <UserExpId>9223372036854775807</UserExpId>
    <UserExpStatus>String content</UserExpStatus>
    <Category>String content</Category>
    <Value>2147483647</Value>
  </Analytics>
  <Analytics Timestamp="2007-05-12T11:20:00">
    <UserExpId>8223372036854775899</UserExpId>
    <UserExpStatus>String content</UserExpStatus>
    <Category>String content</Category>
    <Value>2147483647</Value>
  </Analytics>
</AnalyticsLogs>
```

I am planning to make some custom DTO classes like below.  But for custom Analytics DTO class, I do not know how to make Timestamp data as an XML attribute according to the above request Xml body. Please advice.

public class AnalyticsLogs : List ;

```
public class Analytics
{
   public long UserExpId { get;set;}
   public string UserExpStatus { get; set;}
   public string Category { get;set;}
   public int Value {get; set;}

   // how can I do for XML attribute Timestamp ???  It seems it can not a class property but I am not sure.
   ???
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't you just use the DateTime type?

Comment: You can use **[XmlAttribute]** for your Timestamp property.

Answer (score 1):

[XmlAttribte @msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public class Analytics
{
   public long UserExpId { get;set;}
   public string UserExpStatus { get; set;}
   public string Category { get;set;}
   public int Value {get; set;}

   [XmlAttribute]
   public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

For RestSharp you use attribute `SerializeAsAttribute`. This is [defined here](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/Serializers/SerializeAsAttribute.cs).

```
public class Analytics
{
   public long UserExpId { get;set;}
   public string UserExpStatus { get; set;}
   public string Category { get;set;}
   public int Value {get; set;}

   [SerializeAsAttribute]
   public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I tried this with RestSharp (implicitly serialized XML wih method request.AddBody(my_object), but when I debug the method, I do not see the "Timestamp" field is serialized as XML attribute:  <AnalyticsLogs>
  <Analytics>
    <Timestamp>9/8/2014 5:12:27 PM</Timestamp>
    <UserExpId>0</UserExpId>
    <Category>Category test</Category>
    <Action>Action test</Action>
    <Value>2147483647</Value>
  </Analytics>
</AnalyticsLogs>

RestSharp.Parameter